# I need to go through (iterate) ISearchResult so as to compare the results of eclipse search

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have a `IsearchResult` object I need to go throug (iterate) that so as to compare each result.

[e.g. I look for (ctrl+H) add method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IXJT.png)

[and then I have this results' list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKLYr.png)

I neeed to iterate over this list (it was store int the `ISearchResult` object) and compare each result of the query.

I have this code.

```java
NewSearchUI.addQueryListener(new IQueryListener() {

            @Override
            public void queryStarting(ISearchQuery query) {
                System.out.println("query start " + query);

            }

            @Override
            public void queryRemoved(ISearchQuery query) {
            }

            @Override
            public void queryFinished(ISearchQuery query) {
                System.out.println("query finished " + query);
                System.out.println("result " + query.getSearchResult().getLabel());
                query.getSearchResult().addListener(new ISearchResultListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void searchResultChanged(SearchResultEvent e) {
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void queryAdded(ISearchQuery query) {
            }
```

I need to iterate over the results list and compare or extract information of each result.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I need to iterate the ISearchResult with the listener so as to know each result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over the results.

You must add the `ISearchResultListener` in the `queryStarting` method and save the results as they are given to you in the `searchResultChanged` call.

```java
NewSearchUI.addQueryListener(new IQueryListener() {

        @Override
        public void queryStarting(ISearchQuery query) {
            System.out.println("query start " + query);

            // Starting listening to the search query

            query.getSearchResult().addListener(new ISearchResultListener() {

                @Override
                public void searchResultChanged(SearchResultEvent e) {
                   // TODO save the results as they appear
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void queryRemoved(ISearchQuery query) {
        }

        @Override
        public void queryFinished(ISearchQuery query) {
            System.out.println("query finished " + query);
            System.out.println("result " + query.getSearchResult().getLabel());
        }

        @Override
        public void queryAdded(ISearchQuery query) {
        }
```

Comment: if I do a java search of methods how do I know the name of the methods in the result list?

Comment: No idea. You are going to have to run the code and see what you get.

Comment: it is returning an object of class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.JavaSearchResult`. how can I handle it?

Comment: I don't know, you will have to read the source to see what it makes available.